# Use Purrr reduce(`+`) to Add Column with row sum of numeric variables

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to add a new column with the row sums for each numeric column to my data.  I was able to do it with a nested select_if function but there must be a cleaner way.  Would mutate_if work?

Here's what I have:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(rowsum = (select_if(mtcars, is.numeric) %>% reduce(`+`))
```

Comment: It will be looping within each column

Comment: So would using rowwise() in front or using rowsums() with a mutate be more efficient?

Comment: `rowwise` would be inefficient.  I would use `rowSums`

Comment: Instead of a nested chain, you can do `mtcars %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% reduce(`+`) %>% bind_cols(mtcars, rowsum = .)` or `mtcars %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% rowSums(.) %>% bind_cols(mtcars, rowsum = .)`

Comment: Other than consistent semantics with tidyverse would there be any advantage to reduce over rowSums?

Comment: Yes, if there are NA elements `+` will fail

Comment: I meant the advantage is for `rowSums`